# Trigger event on specific condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a div that will serve as container to other element, I have buttons that add element to that div.

Please see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GkXhe/) for a get an idea about it.

So, what I want to do is to check before adding a new element is the div reached a maximum number of elements that I define, let's say 4.

I can check this condition before every add, but I am sure this is not the best way (we learned that if the code contains copy/paste then is not the best solution) Also, this is just a sample, in my case, I have many buttons..

Is there a way to have a listener like this?

```
$('#container').bind('divFull', function(){
    //My code
});
```

So that I can disable buttons..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to listen to DOM change event, then you can trigger a custom event based on the number of children

```
$('#container').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
    if($(this).children().length>=4){
        $(this).trigger('divFull');
    }
});
```

then you can bind to your custom **divFull** event

```
$('#container').bind('divFull', function(){
    alert('container is full');
    $('button').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GkXhe/2/) based on your example

Answer (score 0):

I change a bit the @skafandri method because the event `DOMSubtreeModified` doesn't work on IE < 9 and it's [depreciated](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified).
The main change is to create a function which will call the `divFull` event if their is 4 children in the container.

```
var checkFull = function() {
    if ($container.children().length === 4) {
        $container.trigger('divFull');
    }
}

$('#button1').click(function(){
    $container.append('<div class="element">some text</div>');
    checkFull();
});
```

Here is [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/GkXhe/3/).

Comment: Basically, what I want to do, is to avoid adding code to buttons, I know how to do this